# Organization needed for a group of similar questions

Tags: discussion, site-organization

I have observed that a particular question has been asked, and separately answered, multiple times.

In chronological order:

- [Does Mathematica have advanced indexing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2821/121)
- [How can I use Max[] in a function that is passed a list not find the max of the list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13414/121)
- [Comparison Operation for Nested Matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51541/121)
- [List operation list1 >= list2 should compare elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83236/121)
- [Element-wise test on List elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95666/121)
- [Greater operator should give greater element](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97918/121)
- [Relational operators on vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110748/121)
- [Maximum brightness of two gray scale images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119994/121) (to a lesser degree)

There are some unique variations among these but there has been a great deal of redundant work in creating these answers.  I am seeking a way to make the existing solutions more evident and if possible group them in a single place for easy reference.

The numeric methods in the first Q&A are highly efficient and directly applicable in many of these cases (as [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/) has been posting as answers) but I do not think they are easy to find.  Whatever "advanced indexing" is and whether or not *Mathematica* has it *sounds* unrelated to many of these, yet many of these questions could be closed as a duplicate of the [2821](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2821/121) if it were written differently.  Could we perhaps turn this into the canonical Q&A with a more transparent title and content, without losing the meaning of the original?

---

In a sort of tangential way [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121) is also related, and has its own cloud of duplicate and near-duplicate questions.  It might be nice to acknowledge one Q&A cluster from within the other.

Comment: This is giving me a lot of trouble: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120522/12

Comment: @Szabolcs `GreaterEqual` is not the only one.New functions added in version 10.0 or later are usually very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the better part of a year with no bites I decided to attempt a canonical reference to the best of my ability.  That now resides at:

- [Can we intelligently control evaluation in Thread?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138661/121)

As referenced for a related class of problems requiring speed on numeric arrays there is:

- [Does Mathematica have advanced indexing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2821/121)

And also as referenced in the question one should view:

- [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121)